# Extracting year and month with ejbql

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

Is it possible to get the year or month out from a date filed with ejbql like this pseudo code
 select year(createdDate), name from table group by year(createdDate) ?

Best regards Anders Olme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you must examine the `Date` object that the query returns yourself by converting it to a `Calendar` and then using `get(Calendar.YEAR)` on it.

Comment: Oki, I'm converting some code from websphere to glassfish and the functions where available there. Guess I have to do it manually then :).

//olme

Comment: There is no extension framework for toplink that would make such statements possible?

Comment: He meant don't do it like that. And he is quite right and serious.

Comment: OK, just that it would make the porting a bit easier since I don't have to introduce new logic. But since it not possible I guess I have no choice :).

/olme